# How to export to excel in JasperReports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to export to excel and csv format in `JasperReports`. For excel I tried by using `JRXlsExporter` class, but it is not exporting. The thing is with "save and cancel" popup window is coming with file type unknown..

```
 file type like "getReportDetail.do"
```

where `getReportDetail.do` is "path" attribute in "action" element of struts config xml. I am calling this `getReportDetail.do` by clicking html button to invoke "action class" to export excel.

I am setting parameter like below

```java
reportExporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint); 
reportExporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, reportStream); 

reportExporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE); 
reportExporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.FALSE);
reportExporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
reportExporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
```

where `reportStream` is object of `ByteArrayOutputStream()`,

`reportExporter` is `JRXlsExporter` object

and the `contenttype` is `response.setContentType("application/xls");`

Any idea why it is happening?

Comment: Try saving the file to your file system first to see if the generated report is bad or if it something after that.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the following headers:

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=report.xls
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code but take care with the version implemented.
**Notice : Export excel with ireport, for ireport 6.0 , java 7**

```
 Map<String, Object> parametro = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                parametro.put("USUARIO", UConstante.NAME_MINISTERIO_USER);
                parametro.put("RUTA_LOGO", PuenteFile.getRutaFiles(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), PuenteFile.RUTA_IMG_LOGO));
                parametro.put("PATH_SYSTEM", rutaFileSystemHD);
                parametro.put("WHERE_DATA", WHERE_REGISTRO);
                parametro.put("WHERE_PROYECTO_USUARIO", WHERE_PROYECTO_USUARIO);
                parametro.put("WHERE_ZONA", WHERE_ZONA);
                parametro.put("NAME_APP", RutaFile.NAME_APP);
                parametro.put("ID_USUARIO", getUsuario().getId());
                parametro.put("ID_PROYECTO", beanProyecto.getId());
                parametro.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", SUBREPORT_DIR);

                System.out.println(">>>>>> PARAMETROS :" + parametro.toString());

              try {
                    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(path, parametro, PgConnector.getConexion());
                    JRXlsExporter xlsExporter = new JRXlsExporter();
                    xlsExporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
                    xlsExporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(PATH_REPORT_FILE + nameExcel);
                    SimpleXlsReportConfiguration xlsReportConfiguration = new SimpleXlsReportConfiguration();
                    SimpleXlsExporterConfiguration xlsExporterConfiguration = new SimpleXlsExporterConfiguration();
                    xlsReportConfiguration.setOnePagePerSheet(true);
                    xlsReportConfiguration.setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenRows(false);
                    xlsReportConfiguration.setDetectCellType(true);
                    xlsReportConfiguration.setWhitePageBackground(false);
                    xlsExporter.setConfiguration(xlsReportConfiguration);
                    xlsExporter.exportReport();

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
```

**and for lower versions of ireport 5.6**

```
          try {
                   JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(new FileInputStream(path), parametro, PgConnector.getConexion());
                    JRXlsExporter exporterXLS = new JRXlsExporter();
                    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
                    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.FALSE);
                    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
                    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
                    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
                    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME,PATH_REPORT_FILE + nameExcel);
                    exporterXLS.exportReport();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();

                }
```